VGA to HDMI conversion with xrandr
I have this VGA to HDMI adapter(the one with audio jack and usb). I use it to connect my HDMI monitor to the VGA port of my PC. It works just fine on Windows and when i use a VirtualBox with linux mint I can see resolution settings up to fullHD. The problem is, when linux mint is my main OS the higher resolution available is 1024x768. I did my research and learned about xrandr and I only managed to solve half of the problem. When I use cvt like this:
cvt 1920 1080 60 it creates the modeline,but xrandr won't add any new mode, I have to use this: cvt -r 1920 1080 but it gives me a reduced version and shows black bands on the sides of the screen. How can i get the fullHD mode in this situation?
